# version `GLIBC_2.29' not found

Tags: docker, rust

I am basing my dockerfile on the `rust` base image.
When deploying my image to an azure container, I receive this log:
`` ./bot: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by ./bot) ``

./bot is my application.
The error also occurs when I perform `docker run` on my Linux Mint desktop.

How can I get GLIBC into my container?

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM rust:1.50
WORKDIR /usr/vectorizer/

COPY ./Cargo.toml /usr/vectorizer/Cargo.toml
COPY ./target/release/trampoline /usr/vectorizer/trampoline
COPY ./target/release/bot /usr/vectorizer/bot
COPY ./target/release/template.svg /usr/vectorizer/template.svg

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get dist-upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y musl-tools && \
    rustup target add x86_64-unknown-linux-musl

CMD ["./trampoline"]
```

Comment: Your container already *has* glibc in it, but it's version 2.28 (`dpkg -l libc-bin`). It sounds like you're compiling your code somewhere else. Use the toolchain inside the container to compile your code and you won't have this problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you compiling in the `Rust` `Debian` image and then coping the binary to another image? Or, are you compiling on your host machine and then moving the binary into the `Rust` `Debian` image?

Comment: What you should do is compile in the container that has `Cargo` installed and then move the binary to another image based on `debian:buster-slim`

Comment: I am building the binary on my Desktop without Docker, then copying that build into my docker hub image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now I don't totally understand the dependencies of your particular project but the below `Dockerfile` should get you started.

What you want to do is compile in an image that has all of your dev dependencies and then move the build artifacts to a much smaller (but compatible) image.

```
FROM rust:1.50 as builder

RUN USER=root

RUN mkdir bot
WORKDIR /bot
ADD . ./
RUN cargo clean && \
    cargo build -vv --release

FROM debian:buster-slim

ARG APP=/usr/src/app

ENV APP_USER=appuser

RUN groupadd $APP_USER \
    && useradd -g $APP_USER $APP_USER \
    && mkdir -p ${APP}

# Copy the compiled binaries into the new container.
COPY --from=builder /bot/target/release/bot ${APP}/bot

RUN chown -R $APP_USER:$APP_USER ${APP}

USER $APP_USER
WORKDIR ${APP}

CMD ["./trampoline"]
```